# Replace multiple column values in a subset dataframe in R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, subset

I want to replace some values of a subset dataframe in R like:

The dataframe I work with:

```
sw1<- swiss[1:5, 1:4]
sw2 <- rbind(sw1,sw1)
```

Here is the subset as defined by some index criteria:

```
sw2[sw2$Examination==15 & sw2$Education==12,]
```

where I want to replace the value for Examination and Education to 1 and 2 respectively.
But how can I assign values to these cells so that I get a sw2 dataframe with the correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question:

```
sw2 <- rbind(sw2,sw2)
```

Where does `sw2` come from? I'm just going to assume your `rbind()` should have been:

```
sw2 <- rbind(sw1, sw1)
```

Anyway, you can replace those two columns like this:

```
sw2[sw2$Examination==15 & sw2$Education==12, c('Examination', 'Education')]  <- list(1, 2)
```

I am isolating the columns that need to be updated with `c('Examination', 'Education')`. `list(1, 2)` will automatically repeat for as many rows as you assign it to (two in this case).

Syntax is a bit funky so I would probably do something longer but easier to read.

```
m <- with(sw2, Examination == 15 & Education == 12)
sw2[m, 'Examination'] <- 1
sw2[m, 'Education'] <- 2
```

Comment: In case one of your criteria columns contains a `NA` value you can add something like `m <- na.omit(m)` to have it work.